# Sprite Kit - cant get custom class data from object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to get the value from my custom class SKNode object. The problem is when I touch on the object no matter what is gives me the same value regardless of the object I touch on.
(blue button) and I cannot get the buttonID,buttonType that I set earlier.

Everything works well, except when I need to get the buttonType, buttonID of the object I touch or drag over.

I am not sure where I am going wrong, any help or push in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

here is my custom class .h file.

```
 #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

  @interface ButtonNode : SKNode {

          SKNode *buttonCustom;

  }

  @property int buttonType, buttonColumn, buttonID, xPos, yPos;

  @property NSString *buttonName;

   -(id)initWithButtonType:(int)buttonType;


  @end
```

Here is my custom class .m file

```
#import "ButtonNode.h"


 #define kBoxSize CGSizeMake(40, 40)


 @implementation ButtonNode

 @synthesize buttonColumn,buttonType,buttonID,xPos,yPos,buttonName;


 static const uint32_t blueCategory = 1 << 0;
 static const uint32_t redCategory = 1 << 1;
 static const uint32_t greenCategory = 1 << 2;
 static const uint32_t yellowCategory = 1 << 3;


-(id)initWithButtonType:(int)buttonType {
     self = [super init];

     if (buttonType == 1) {
        NSLog(@"BLUE BUTTON CREATE");
         [self addButtonBlue];
     }
    if (buttonType == 2) {
       NSLog(@"RED BUTTON CREATE");
        [self addButtonRed];
    }
   if (buttonType == 3) {
      NSLog(@"Green BUTTON CREATE");
       [self addButtonGreen];
   }
   if (buttonType == 4) {
     NSLog(@"Yellow BUTTON CREATE");
      [self addButtonYellow];
   }
     return self;
 }

- (void) addButtonBlue {

    SKSpriteNode *rect;

       //button type 1
        rect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:kBoxSize];

        int tmpInt = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSString *tmpName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tmpInt];
        rect.name = tmpName; //unique name.

       rect.name = @"1";

       rect.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blueCategory;
       rect.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = blueCategory;
       rect.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = blueCategory | redCategory | yellowCategory | greenCategory;

        rect.position = CGPointMake(xPos , yPos );
       [self addChild:rect];
}

- (void) addButtonRed {

    SKSpriteNode *rect;

   //button type 2
   rect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:kBoxSize];

   int tmpInt = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
   NSString *tmpName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tmpInt];
   rect.name = tmpName; //unique name.

   rect.name = @"2";

    rect.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = redCategory;
    rect.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = redCategory;
    rect.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = blueCategory | redCategory | yellowCategory | greenCategory;

   rect.position = CGPointMake(xPos , yPos );
    [self addChild:rect];
}

- (void) addButtonGreen {

    SKSpriteNode *rect;

    //button type 3
    rect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:kBoxSize];

    int tmpInt = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *tmpName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tmpInt];

   rect.name = tmpName; //unique name.

   rect.name = @"3";

   rect.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = greenCategory;
   rect.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = greenCategory;
   rect.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = blueCategory | redCategory | yellowCategory | greenCategory;

   rect.position = CGPointMake(xPos , yPos );
   [self addChild:rect];
}

- (void) addButtonYellow {

   SKSpriteNode *rect;

   //button type 4
   rect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:kBoxSize];

   int tmpInt = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
   NSString *tmpName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tmpInt];

   rect.name = tmpName; //unique name.

   rect.name = @"4";

   rect.physicsBody.mass = 1;
   rect.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = yellowCategory;
   rect.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = yellowCategory;
   rect.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = blueCategory | redCategory | yellowCategory | greenCategory;

   rect.position = CGPointMake(xPos , yPos );
   [self addChild:rect];
}

@end
```

Here is where I create the buttons.
(at top of file with rest of global ivar )
ButtonNode * newButton;

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

    //create random Int
    int tmpInt = arc4random() %3;

    NSLog(@"tmp %i" ,tmpInt);

    column1.position = CGPointMake(100, self.frame.size.height - 40);

    if (tmpInt == 0) {
        //button type 1
        newButton = [[ButtonNode alloc] initWithButtonType:1];
        newButton.xPos = column1.position.x;
        newButton.yPos = column1.position.y *i;
        newButton.buttonID = 344224351; //unique name
        newButton.buttonColumn = 2;
        newButton.buttonType = 1;
        [column1 addChild:newButton];
        blueTotal++;
        totalButtons++;
        column1Total++;
}
    if (tmpInt == 1) {
        //button type 2
        newButton = [[ButtonNode alloc] initWithButtonType:2];
        newButton.xPos = column1.position.x;
        newButton.yPos = column1.position.y *i;
        newButton.buttonID = 344224351; //unique name
        newButton.buttonColumn = 2;
        newButton.buttonType = 1;
        [column1 addChild:newButton];
        redTotal++;
        totalButtons++;
        column1Total++;
    }

 }
```

Here is the Part that is not working correctly.

```
     - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

       UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
       CGPoint loc = [touch locationInNode:self];
       NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:loc];

       for (SKNode *nod in nodes) {

          NSString *tmp = nod.name;
             if (tmp.length !=0) {

                NSString * tmpType = nod.name;

               if ([tmpType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Node Type: %@", nod.name);
                    previousButton = @"1";
                    NSLog (@"%d",newButton.buttonType);
               }

               if ([tmpType isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
                   NSLog(@"Node Type: %@", nod.name);
                   previousButton = @"2";
                   NSLog (@"%d",newButton.buttonType);
               }

              if ([tmpType isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
                NSLog(@"Node Type: %@", nod.name);
                 previousButton = @"3";
                  NSLog (@"%d",newButton.buttonType);

            }

            if ([tmpType isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
                NSLog(@"Node Type: %@", nod.name);
                previousButton = @"4";
                NSLog (@"%d",newButton.buttonType);

            }

           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SKNode` does not have those properties.

Try this just inside your for loop  :

```
ButtonNode *myButton = (ButtonNode *)nod;
```

That will cast `nod` correctly as a `ButtonNode`, and you can use `myButton` like this :

```
NSLog(@"%d",myButton.buttonType);
```

Then you should be able to access the properties  you have defined in the `ButtonNode` class.

You might only want to do that cast if you are sure it's a ButtonNode, but was just trying to help you understand why those properties would NEVER be accessible given your current code.

Also, your usage of `newButton` in that loop in `touchesBegan` is not what I think you 'think' it is. It's going to be the last button created, not the current node being stored in `nod` in the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I tried your suggestion. But when I make the modifications like you suggested, it crashes whenever I press a on a square. The newButton.buttonType was just the last point I was at when trying to figure out the problem :) Any other tips?

Comment: Also, is there a way to add a custom property like "buttonID" etc to a SKNode? basically that Is what I am trying to figure out. That then could be accessed like "button1.buttonType = @"something";

Comment: As I said, you you might need to determine if it's actually a `ButtonNode` first. If the app crashes, I can't help you if you don't give a error message etc :)  My answer is not to debug your app, it's just to answer your question about how to make the properties accessible. I assure you that if `nod` is a ButtonNode, the code above will work. If not... all bets are off.

Comment: Also, you saying that it crashes when you press on a square, could even be another issue. Do you get the NSLog output ? Put that line right after the cast. If you get the log and it displays the buttonType, then it worked and you have a brand new crash bug to hunt down. :)

Comment: Also, this question is about how to access the properties of your custom class. Other questions should be made in another post. Answering a whole list of questions in the comments, is defeating the purpose of the format of this site.

Comment: thanks for the advice and tips, I will do some reading/research tomorrow when I wake up(its 3:00 am here lol) and get back to you.